# Get contents of a url using Proxy, in php but without curl

Tags: php, sockets, proxy

I have to fetch content of some urls by using proxies from a list.

All proxies requires authentication (i have username and passwords as well).

Problem is i don't have curl installed on server , so can't use curl.

I tried using sockets but having problem using that.

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: What problem were you having with the sockets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `stream_context_create` with the `proxy` option (see here for details: http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php ). Then you can access the file using the standard functions `fopen`, `file_get_contents` .

Answer (score -1):

try using this:

```
$text = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```

or

```
$text = file_get_contents('http://user:pass@www.example.com/');
```